# Sum of multiple results

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I'm trying to make a simple script that visualizes runtastic data but I'm having a little problem.
I run the following script, which only displays the latest activity.

```
$myRuntasticActivities = $runtastic->getActivities(null, null, 2017);
$distanceKM = $myRuntasticActivities[0]->distance / 1000;
echo "In 2017 I ran $distanceKM KM";
```

Result output: **In 2017 I ran 6,8KM.**

If I change the [0] to [1] I get the second most recent activity.
How can I add all results up? I believe the runtastic script is limited to showing the latest 419 results. 
Is there a way to add 0 -> 419?

I've tried array_sum, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: A `for` or `foreach` loop.

Comment: `array_sum()` needs an array of numbers, you have an array of objects. You could use `array_map()` to extract all the distances from that, then sum those with `array_sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce`.

```
$sum = array_reduce($myRuntasticActivities, function($carry, $item){
    return $carry + $item->distance;
}, 0) / 1000;
```

You could use a `foreach`.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($myRuntasticActivities as $act) {
    $sum += $act->distance / 1000;
}
```

You could use a simple `for`.

```
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myRuntasticActivities); $i++) {
    $sum += $myRuntasticActivities[$i]->distance / 1000;
}
```